# Get_posts not returning any posts when used with switch_to_blog

Tags: get-posts, post-type, switch-to-blog

I'm attempting to pull in some order information from the "`shop_order`" `post_type`.

This is on a multisite network, so I'm using `switch_to_blog(1)`. When I set the post type as "post" it works great and I get the posts from the correct site. When I set the `post_type` to "`shop_order`" I get nothing, despite there being 20,000 '`shop_order`' records in the database.

```
switch_to_blog(1);
$args = array (
        //'post_type' => 'post',
        'post_type' => 'shop_order',
        'posts_per_page' => 2,
        );
$posts = get_posts( $args );
restore_current_blog();
var_dump($posts);
```

Comment: probably `post_status`, which defaults to `publish`

Comment: Do not use `$posts` as local variable, rather use something like `$posts_array`

Comment: @milo, nailed it. If you want to post that as the answer so I can mark it as correct? Thanks man.

Answer (score 1):

Per @Milo's comment:

> probably post_status, which defaults to publish – Milo 53 mins ago

So I just set `'post_status' => 'wc_completed'` in my args and I'm good.